# Is there any mistake in my code? I'm a newbie

Tags: c

when I give maximum values to a and b the code works perfectly but when the maximum is given input to c or d, the code doesn't works. Can anyone help me with this one?

I've already visited websites and done my research but I couldn't find anything.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void) {
 int a, b, c, d;

 scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
 printf("the enter no.: is %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);

 if(a > b) {
    if(a > c) {
        if(a > d) {
            printf("%d is greater",a);
        }
    }
 } else if(b > a) {
    if(b > c) {
        if(b > d) {
            printf("%d is greater", b);
        }
    }
  } else if(c > a) { 
    if(c > b) {
        if(c > d) {
            printf("%d is greater", c);
        }
    }
  } else if(d > a) {
    if(d > c) {
        if(d > b) {
            printf("%d is greater", d);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The output should be same for all the variables but still a and b is giving outputs as expected and c and d doesn't.

Comment: You should regroup the `if` 3 by 3, it changes nothing, but the behaviour would be more clear. It's a question of psychology. `main` should really return int, it is auto corrected at compile time, so control that yourself.

Comment: your logic is not valid, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    printf("the enter no.: is %d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
    if(a > b && a > c && a > d)
        printf("%d is greater\n", a);
    else if(b > a && b > c && b > d)
        printf("%d is greater\n", b);
    else if(c > a && c > b && c > d)
        printf("%d is greater\n", c);
    else
        printf("%d is greater\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not just a refactor, unlike the original code this is correct

Answer (score 4):

your way to do is wrong, for instance with the input 2 1 4 3 `if(a>b)` is true but `if(a>c)` is false so you do nothing more and you do not detect the max number

out of your problem I also encourage you to check 4 valid *int* was enter checking `scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d)` returns 4

a proposal :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a,b,c,d;

  if (scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d) != 4)
    fprintf(stderr, "error while entering the 4 values\n");
  else {
    printf("the enter no.: is %d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);

    int max = a;

    if (b > max)
      max = b;
    if (c > max)
      max = c;
    if (d > max)
      max = d;

    printf("the greater is %d\n", max);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
1 2 4 3
the enter no.: is 1 2 4 3
the greater is 4
```

Of course there is an other way to do without memorizing all the numbers

Comment: you may want to make it consistent by changing the `if (b > a)` to `if (b > max)` :-)

Comment: @AhmedMasud is funny because in my head I written `if (b > max)` ^^ So yes I agree with you

Comment: hehe you'd set it up that way.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I just hope you are not able to read in my head, can be dangerous (but not sure if this is for you or me ^^)

Comment: This definitely deserves to be selected as the answer. It works when the maximum value is shared by multiple numbers, and it cuts down on the number of conditional evaluations by two thirds.

Comment: @Pierce yes your proposal makes a lot of tests, I was about to put that in a remark on your answer but some people do not like to have remark from other people answering (this is not my case) so I didn't ;-). If I can give you an advice : do not just put code in an answer, describe it and/or explain the problem(s) in the question

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions depends on one another, but they shouldn't be.

Meaning, the second high level condition (else if(b>a)) would be checked only if a is not greater then b.

For example, given the input of:

> a = 1
>
> b = 2
>
> c = 3
>
> d = 4

The second high level condition would be true (b is greater than a), and so, no other condition would be checked at all (the condition if d is the greatest would not be checked, and the line won't be printed).

To solve this issue, you can ether change the conditions to make every one of them in a single if (with && (and) between them), or you can change your code to always use "if"s, instead of your "else if".

Answer (score 0):

It is the order of your program which is causing the problem.
If you put c and d as maximum but if b>a or a>b it will enter the first two if-statements and it will not reach the two last statements.
Try to put c or d as maximum and choose two numbers such that a=b. This should work.

Comment: and you can check the proposals by the other contributors they are all good.